# Regular expression without spaces or special characters

Tags: php, regex, passwords, expression

I am new to regular expressions and I need a regex for php username that matches

```
no spaces
```

---

```
no special characters
```

---

in length 8, max 32

and also a regex for password that matches

---

```
alphanumeric have at least one digit and one character
```

---

```
no spaces
```

Comment: You're new to regex? Here's a [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: These posts are so useful when you have a common regex problem. SMH for voting them down

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following [**REGEX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) :

```
^\S+\w{8,32}\S{1,}
```

- `^` means *beginning of line*
- `\S` means all characters but not a space or a tab
- `+` mean at least one character
- `\w`  means an alphanumeric character including `_`
- `{8,32}` means at least 8 characters, and max 32
- `\S` still means all characters but not a space or a tab
- `{1,}` means at least 1 item

Comment: That means the string is a minimum of 10 characters. It's not limitited in size, as `\S+` and `\S{` can be of arbitrary length.